# Prevent double voting with AngularFire, Firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I'm running into trouble saving and retrieving values in Firebase using Angularfire v2 (http://angularfire.com/documentationv2.html , v2 is necessary because v1 seemed unable to order items by priority)

It's a simple vote-up-down app using Persona Login for authorization, the problem comes when the user votes on a 'story', I want to add his user id to 'story/users', but it seems the only way to do that without erasing all the other values is to use '$add'(push), which throws in a random key name which I have no idea how to query against.

So to prevent double voting I have to somehow ask if 'story/users' already has that user's id in there.

```
story---
        users---
                -J9LrtJwXnCI3ZYqsIz1: user-1
                -J9Lriauhfdoaiuhfafd: user-2
```

Does anybody have any idea how to find out if user-1 is in 'story/users'?

Keep in mind Angularfire v2 has some major changes.

And if anybody has a better idea I'd be happy to hear it (but I'm really trying to avoid saving it as user-1/story-id, for other reasons)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the records by the user's ID, rather than a random push id. For example, you could create a `votes` path, and keep track of who has voted there:

```
/votes/user-1
/votes/user-2
```

Then you can write a security rule to prevent double voting as follows:

```
{
   "rules": {
       "votes": {
            "$record_id":  {
                // something like this
                ".write":  "auth.id === $record_id && data.val() === true"
            }
       }
   }
}
```

You can perform the set in V2 angularFire by using the $set and $child commands.

```
dataRef.$child( user.id ).set( true ); // for example
```

Comment: Shoot Kato you're everywhere!  I solved my main problem by avoiding the random keys with:  `$scope.addUser = $firebase(new Firebase("https://***.firebaseio.com/story/" + story_id + "/users/" + $scope.auth.user.id));   $scope.addUser.vote = "upvote";   $scope.addUser.$save("vote");`  WHew!  Security rules are next on my list.  0.5.0 is vast improvement, by the way.

Comment: Very nice. So the last step is to make sure users can't write to any users/user_id that is not their own (that's where the security rules will play in)

Comment: I think I managed that but I ran into trouble trying to make sure they don't super-charge their vote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255224/trouble-with-firebase-security-rule-involving-getpriority